# Produce the set difference of two List Items in C#

Tags: c#, sorting, lambda

I have 2 Lists available to me. I need to gather the data that is no longer used.

For Example

List 1:

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
- 5

List 2:

- 1
- 2
- 4
- 5
- 6

The result data set needs to be.

Items not Included in List 2:

- 3

I was hoping to use something along the lines of:

```
var itemsNotInList2 = List2.Except(List1).ToList();
```

Comment: Reverse it:  `var itemsNotInList2 = List1.Except(List2).ToList();`

Comment: For anyone wanting to see an example of IEqualityComparer and a great explanation of it.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/762203/Csharp-LINQ-and-IEqualityComparer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're dealing with `List<int>` in this example then you have the right idea, just the args reversed. It should be;

```
var itemsNotInList2 = List1.Except(List2).ToList();
```

Think about how to state this in plain English. To get `itemsNotInList2` I want to take everything in `List1` *except* what's in `List2`. Your code in the question is giving you items that are in `List2` but not in `List1` which there are none of since `List2` is a subset of `List1`

Note that this approach is often not suitable for reference types because the default comaparer will compare the references themselves. In order to do a similar operate with objects you'd have to implement `IEqualityComparer` and invoke the overload which accepts that as it's third argument. For example if you were dealing with a `List<Person>` and `Person` had a `public string Ssid` you could define `Equal` with `return p1.Ssid == p2.Ssid` and use that as your basis of comparison. You can find examples of this on msdn should you need it.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Ssid;
    // other properties and methods
}

public class PersonSsidEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Person>
{
      public bool Equal(Person lhs, Person rhs) 
      {
          return lhs.Ssid == rhs.Ssid
      }

      public int GetHashCode(Person p)
      {
          return p.Value.GetHashCode();
      }
}
```

Now as an example;

```
  List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
  List<Person> otherPeople = new List<Person>();
  Person p1 = new Person("123"); // pretend this constructor takes an ssid
  Person p2 = new Person("123");
  Person p3 = new Person("124");
  Person p4 = p1;
```

Now some examples using the data I set up above;

```
  people.Add(p1);
  people.Add(p3);
  otherPeople.Add(p2);

  var ThemPeople = people.Except(otherPeople);
  // gives you p1 and p3

  var ThemOtherPeople = people.Except(otherPeople, new PersonSsidEqualityComparar());
  // only gives you p3

  otherPeople.Add(p4);
  var DoingReferenceComparesNow = people.Except(otherPeople);
  // gives you only p3 cause p1 == p4 (they're the same address)
```

Comment: I see, I am actually using objects, any chance you can point me to an example on msdn or show me a proof of concept?

Comment: @BradyLiles I updated with an example that uses objects and implements `IEqualityComparar`. Note that you can combine some other LINQ operators to achieve the same results without implementing `IEqualityComparar`, it's just necessary to use `Except`.

Comment: Wow, you really went all out.
Thank you so much for your help!!!
I also definitely understand why this is necessary too.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var itemsNotInList2 = List1.Except(List2).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're comparing objects, you should probably provide your own [Equality Comparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151(v=vs.110).aspx).

For example:

```
public class YourClass
{
    public int Value;
}

public class YourClassEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<YourClass>
{
    public bool Equals(YourClass x, YourClass y)
    {
        return x.Value == y.Value;
    }
    public int GetHashCode(YourClass obj)
    {
        return obj.Value.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

So you can use an overload of Except that takes an instance of your equality comparer:

```
var list = l1.Except(l2, new YourClassEqualityComparer());
```